# Un-glusterize a disk?

Tags: glusterfs

How can I get back a bare disk (with the data) that was used in a simple 2 nodes replicas GlusterFS cluster ?

Would removing the `.glusterfs` directory be sufficient or are the files themselves somehow tied to GlusterFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to removing the `.glusterfs` directory, you would also need to remove the various extended attributes which gluster sets on each of the files/directorys in the brick.